# Using custom AuthProvider with Telerik Reporting ServiceStack assembly or any external assembly

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, servicestack, telerik-reporting

Telerik's latest reporting release has an assembly that contains A number of ServiceStack services that return report data to a client. It works great with their HTML5 viewer. The problem I am trying to solve is I want to require authentication to call the reporting services so not just anyone can call the service.

The way the service works is you just create a class that inherits from abstract class ReportHostBase (which inherits AppHostBase), implement a couple functions in ReportHostBase, wire it up in your Global.asax and it's ready to go. All the Service implementations are inside the compiled Telerik assembly. I have no way to add the Authenticate attribute to them so I am at a loss on how to for any sort of authentication on these services.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can add add attributes to external Request DTO's you don't control by [dynamically adding attributes at runtime](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/RuntimeAttributeTests.cs), e.g:

```
typeof(ExternalDto)
    .AddAttributes(new AuthenticateAttribute());
```

Comment: The AddAttributes method doesn't appear to be defined in System.Type. Is this an extension method within ServiceStack assembly somewhere?

Comment: @user3617348 yeah it's an extension method in the base `ServiceStack` namespace in `ServiceStack.Text.dll`.